# Using C++-objects in Objective-C-blocks

Tags: ios, performance, objective-c-blocks, objective-c++

I have a C++-object `obj` which I want to access within a block:

```
MyCppClass obj;
void(^myBlock)() = ^{
    obj.test();
};
```

The problem here is that `obj` gets copied into the block, but I want to use a reference to the original object. I could use a pointer instead:

```
MyCppClass obj;
MyCppClass *objP = &obj;
void(^myBlock)() = ^{
    objP->test();
};
```

But I think dereferencing pointers takes more time than using references. (Performance is critical, because in my project such a block is called for each pixel of a large image.)

How can I access the object within the block?

Comment: "dereferencing pointers takes more time than using references" I can't image how is this possible. and for critical performance code, you may found using C++11 lambda make it faster since it can be inlined by compiler

Comment: Why do you think dereferencing pointers takes more time?  Have you profiled to see if that makes a significant difference?  Copying the entire object is probably a lot more expensive than passing a pointer, and using a reference is essentially the same thing.

Comment: I fear that when using pointers the compiler is less able to optimize the code, because it doesn't know that the actual object has a fixed memory-offset relative to the block. As I don't know how to use references in this case, I can't test and compare the performance.

Comment: But using c++11-lambdas actually seems to be a pretty nice idea. Thanks Bryan! :)

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a pointer is faster than a function call or a C++ method call,which involves several pointer dereferences to look up the method in the class, and then an actual function call, which actually allocates memory on the stack, saves away some registers to RAM, and then does the reverse when it returns. So don't worry about performance here. If the profiler shows you that a single pointer de-reference causes performance issues, you have bigger problems, and you should probably drop down to hand-crafted assembler, and forget using C++ classes or blocks. Also, it's a very rare thing.

Use a pointer, or a C++ reference (the latter is the same under the hood, but it's harder to shoot yourself in the foot with it, and code stays more readable). Just keep in mind that this is only a solution if you are going to use the block in the same function as (or a function called by) the current function.

Because the C++ object is on the stack, it will go away, so if whoever you hand the block to copies it and calls it later, the pointer will be invalid. In the best case you will crash. In the worst case, the spot on the RAM chip that was used for that object is already in use for something else again, and you'll overwrite some other bit of memory, and cause a seemingly unrelated crash.

So, if you want to keep the block around, you'll have to do 'objP = new MyCppClass' to create the object, and later do 'delete objP' (maybe in the last call to the block, if you can detect that and don't need the object after that) to get rid of it.

Comment: "Dereferencing a pointer is faster than a function call or a C++ method call"
That's not true. It depends on what is known about the function-call at compile-time. If you only use static types and create the object locally on the stack, the compiler can arbitrarily unroll and inline-expand the function-call, until there won't happen any pointer-dereferencing at run-time (besides storing the result of the computation in a dynamic array somewhere in memory).

Comment: But if you explicitly use pointers, the compiler might not be able to do any optimizations at all and pointer-dereferencing becomes inevitable. Additionally avoiding pointers typically leads to a more readable and less error-prone code.

Comment: @DominikSeibold: If the method is not virtual, the compiler also knows at compile time exactly the function call to make, and can similarly inline it.

Comment: @newacct Yes, you are right. My point should have been that if the compiler already knows on which type I'm calling the function, because it is static, AND the object is on the stack in immediate vicinity, on the one hand there wouldn't be any pointers involved to unknown objects in the far system memory, and on the other the compiler could make more advanced deductions on the values of the object and optimize even more.